# Autocomplete not working with php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to make a simple auto complete script with Javascript and php but its not working at all. Thanks for the help ahead of time!
 This is my html.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https:ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/countries.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Countries</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="country">Country: </label>
        <input type="text" name="country" id="country">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the Javascript

```
$(function() { // Turn the text input into an Autocomplete widget:
        $('#country').autocomplete({
            source: 'resources/countries.php',
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
```

And the php

```
<?php // countries.php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$data = array();
$countries = array( 'Afghaistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'Andorra');
if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
    foreach ($countries as $country) {
        if (stripos($country, $_GET['term']) !== false) $data[] = $country; 
} // End of FOREACH.
} // End of IF.
echo json_encode($data);
```

Thanks again you all are awesome!

Comment: Why are you loading jQuery 1.10.2 (cdn) **and** 1.7.1?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: have you checked whether php displays proper json? what does the browser display when you go to resources/countries.php?

Comment: here's a tuturial that may help you. http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Im in college now and completely clueless and am just following a book. code for code but the book is full of erorros so Im lost. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I took out 1.7.1 thanks!  TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
[Break On This Error]  
Thanks for the tuturial!!
minLength: 2

Comment: Try adding flush(); after you echo json...

Answer (score -2):

From what I can see, you are encoding your results with JSON in the PHP file, but you're not decoding from JSON in jQuery, try using `jQuery.parseJSON()`

Comment: autocomplete expects JSON encoded data (http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

Comment: $.autocomplete does that on its own.